# How do you give your paragraphs half a line worth of space?

Tags: html, css, stylus

How would I go about adding half a line worth of space after each paragraph? See the middle mockup below.

[image]

I've noticed 1em isn't the same height as 1 linebreak so that can't be the correct solution.

Comment: can you explain your problem ? and your solution ? and also post the relevant code here

Comment: Relevant code is below.

Comment: this is the code for the solution ... you need to state a clear issue and then how you solve it ... it's seems you simply had a requirement for your dev and you found a workaround, so what is the issue or the problem ? ... you said in the question (where there is no question mark) --> `I want to be able to add half a line break` : am not sure if it's an issue, as we can add line break using a lot of method and also control the size we need.

Comment: I've revised the question to hopefully explain the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use half your current lineheight.

```
p:after{
    content: "\00a0";
    display: block;
    line-height: ($yourLineHeight/2);
}
```

or

```
p{
    margin-bottom: ($yourLineHeight/2);
}
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/qkeave/pen/oqQLBN

~ Edited to reflect comments

Comment: why a pseudo element and not just `margin-bottom: ($yourLineHeight/2);`?

Comment: I think that would work too but I prefer the pseudo incase there isn't a unit that the lineheight is set it.

Comment: @masterfloda exactly as i commented above, i don't see why exactly the pseudo element as we can do it with a lot of manner and this is simply a need not an issue ...we can use padding-bottom, control the `<br>` tag, etc etc